# can not copy images to iPhone DCIM folder

Tags: ios, appium

I am automating one iOS test case where I need to add some images to media partition of iOS device. I used iFuse to mount media partition to my OS X.

I used

> $ifuse mountdir

Command to mount media partion to mountdir on my hardisk. Mounting is successful. When I do ls -l , I could see all the folder on my iOS device. But when I try to copy image using either finder or cp command, it fails.

Sometimes copying using finder fails but still file is created. But it is not shown in Photos app on iOS device.
Please note this question is not just about copying images to iOS device. It is about using a command line option like iFuse to be incorporated in test automation.

Comment: You need a utility that copies data (in this case, photos) to the iOS Device? You're going to have difficulty setting up the database and then launching the Appium server unless you use `--no-reset`

Comment: Yes sheeptest, I need utility that copies data to iOS device. Someone suggested me to use iFuse.https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ifuse